# Skills list is not updated when new skill is added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

There is an accordion of Skills and Experiences in background component. When the title on the skills accordion is clicked then the modal will pop up with skill form which when filled and submitted then the modal closes and the list of skill should get update but it is not updating. I have to refresh to see the changes in the skill list. Here is how i have done

```
class Background extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    show: false,
    componentName: null,
    activeIndex: 0
  };

  handleModal = (action, componentName) =>
    this.setState(state => ({
      show: action,
      componentName
    }));

  render() {
    const { show, activeIndex, componentName } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ProfileWrapper>
          <Query query={BACKGROUND_QUERY}>
            {({
              data: { experiences, skills, languages, educations } = {},
              loading
            }) => {
              if (loading) {
                return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
              } else {
                return (
                  <Grid columns={2}>
                    <Accordion
                      index={1}
                      onToggle={this.handleToggle}
                      css="max-width: 100%; min-width: 200px;"
                    >
                      <Accordion.Title>
                        <Title>
                            Skills (
                            {`${skills !== undefined && skills.edges.length}`})
                        </Title>
                      </Accordion.Title>
                      <Accordion.Content>
                        <Content>
                          {skills !== undefined && skills.edges.length > 0 && (
                            <span>
                              {skills.edges.map(skill => {
                                return (
                                  <React.Fragment key={skill["node"].id}>
                                    <span key={skill["node"].id}>
                                      <Chip>{skill["node"].title}</Chip>
                                    </span>
                                  </React.Fragment>
                                );
                              })}
                            </span>
                          )}
                        </Content>
                      </Accordion.Content>
                    </Accordion>
                    <Modal
                      position="centerCenter"
                      open={show}
                      onClose={() => this.handleModal(false, null)}
                    >
                      <React.Fragment>
                        {componentName !== null &&
                          componentName === "experiences" && (
                            <Experiences experiences={experiences} />
                          )}
                        {componentName !== null &&
                          componentName === "skills" && (
                            <Skills skills={skills} />
                          )}

                      </React.Fragment>
                    </Modal>
                  </Grid>
                );
              }
            }}
          </Query>
        </ProfileWrapper>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Background;


const Skills = ({ handleSubmit, ...props }) => {
  const formSubmit = async (val, mutation) => {
    const {
      data: { skill: response }
    } = await mutation({
      variables: val
    });
    console.log('response', response);
    if (response.success) {
      props.closeModal();
      toast.success("New Skill Added!");
    }
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Mutation mutation={CREATE_SKILL}>
        {mutation => {
          return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(val => formSubmit(val, mutation))}>
              <Field name="title" label="Title" component={TextField} />
              <Button>
                <Button.Primary>Add Skill</Button.Primary>
                <Button.Secondary>Cancel</Button.Secondary>
              </Button>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Mutation>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: "skillsProfile",
    enableReinitialize: true,
    destroyOnUnmount: false
  })
)(Skills);
```

why optimistic ui update is not working here when Query is done in background component?

Comment: Are you sure another API call to background_query is happening once the modal is closed?

Comment: I checked it now and it's not happening. when the state is changed(show state because handleModal triggers the changes) after hitting submit button, it then goes to render function but does not call the api.

Comment: If its graphql query, I remember, graphql caches data and it returns cached data if the inputs to query are same,

Comment: How can i optimistically update it then? Do you have any idea?

Comment: May be you  can pass options to graphql query. One of them is fetchPolicy. Take a look at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy

Comment: I found the solution. I need to use refetchQueries in mutate({})

Comment: i got your comment just after posting mine. I will try with fetch-policy as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#update):

> Sometimes when you perform a mutation, your GraphQL server and your Apollo cache become out of sync. This happens when the update you’re performing depends on data that is already in the cache; for example, deleting and adding items to a list. We need a way to tell Apollo Client to update the query for the list of items. This is where the update function comes in!

There's no way for Apollo to know what sort of operations your server is doing when it executes a mutation (adding one or more rows, deleting a row, etc.) -- all it has to go off is the data that's returned by the mutation. It can match this data against objects that are already in the cache and update them accordingly, but that's it. If there are any fields that were cached and need to be updated as a result of your mutation, you need to explicitly tell Apollo how to do this (side note, these could be fields that return a List of `Skills`, but they could be literally any other fields that were impacted by the mutation).

Your `update` function for adding a skill, for example, would look something like this:

```js
update={(cache, { data: { addSkill } }) => {
  // assumes addSkill resolves to a single Skill
  const { skills, ...rest } = cache.readQuery({ query: BACKGROUND_QUERY });
  cache.writeQuery({
    query: BACKGROUND_QUERY,
    data: { skills: skills.concat([addSkill]), ...rest },
  });
}}
```

See the docs for additional examples. It's also worthwhile noting that when using `readQuery` or `writeQuery`, you will need to pass in the appropriate variables if your query takes any.

While you ***can*** refetch your queries (for example, by specifying them as part of `refetchQueries`), it's largely unnecessary for simple updates to the cache and obviously slower than just using `update` since it requires another round-trip to your server. Additionally, `update` even works with [optimistic updates to your UI](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/optimistic-ui.html).

Comment: i think this is applicable only when creating a new skill and adding this new skill in a list but wont work if we edit particular skill because its concatinating.

Comment: Your question included code for a `CREATE_SKILL` mutation, so that's what I based the example on. You shouldn't use the example verbatim but adopt it as needed. If you have a mutation that only updates an existing item, you probably don't need to define an `update` function for it. If you're not seeing the UI update after such a mutation, there's other factors at play.

Comment: @Serenity Based on your comment, your post doesn't seem to match your actual question. If you have an update mutation that's not updating the UI as expected, you should update your code appropriately. It'd also be helpful to see the actual queries themselves.